# How do I query for Distinct Records using Query Criteria on a Queryable State

Tags: corda

I've a query-able state and I want do a SQL query like :
`SELECT DISTINCT column1,column2,.. FROM table_name;`

How can I do that using Vault Query and Vault Custom Query Criteria.
Even if I get the whole state which has these distinct columns, I'm fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Corda 3, there is no way to do this using `VaultQuery`/`VaultCustomQueryCriteria`. You need to connect directly to the node's database via JDBC.